# Jquery Validate bespoke method not called for empty field (other fields ok)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have an input form which includes a 3 part date of birth.

I have written a custom validation method to validate the 3 parts, it is called if one of the 3 fields is entered however I need to have it called if all or any of the fields is empty.

I have console.log commands so I can see if the method is called, if you click submit with empty fields you can see it isn't called, enter a number into one of the date fields and it will be called.

All the similar issues I could find were where the form isn't validated at all, this does validate the other field.

There is sample code at https://jsfiddle.net/zacmarshall/Lrvsachp/8/

html

```
 <form id="form1"><br/><br/><br/>
        <div id="form_group_puid" class="form-group">
            <span class="label">field1</span>
            <span class="hint"></span>
            <div id="error_location_puid"></div>
            <input class="input !-width-one-quarter" id="puid" name="puid"  required>
        </div>

        <div id="form_group_date_of_birth" class="form-group">
            <fieldset class="fieldset" aria-describedby="date_of_birth_hint" role="group">
                <span class="label">Date of birth</span>
                <span id = "tour_start_date_hint" class="hint">e.g. 31 3 1980</span>

                <div class="date-input" id="date_of_birth">
                <div id="error_location_date_of_birth"></div>
                    <div class="date-input__item">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="label date-input__label" for="date_of_birth_day">
                                Day
                            </label>
                            <div id="error_location_date_of_birth_day"></div>
                            <input class="input " id="date_of_birth_day" name="date_of_birth_day" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="1" max="31" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="date-input__item">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="label date-input__label" for="date_of_birth_month">
                                Month
                            </label>
                            <div id="error_location_date_of_birth_month"></div>
                            <input class="input " id="date_of_birth_month" name="date_of_birth_month" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="1" max="12" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="date-input__item">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="label date-input__label" for="date_of_birth_year">
                                Year
                            </label>
                            <div id="error_location_date_of_birth_year"></div>
                            <input class="input" id="date_of_birth_year" name="date_of_birth_year" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="1900" max="2018" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </fieldset>

        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

/* Custom validation method to validate a date based on several fields: */
$.validator.addMethod("datemultiple1", function(value, element, params) {
    console.log("in datemultiple1");
    var daySelector = params[0],
        monthSelector = params[1],
        yearSelector = params[2],
        day = parseInt($(daySelector).val(), 10),
        month = parseInt($(monthSelector).val(), 10),
        year = parseInt($(yearSelector).val(), 10);
        //dateEntered = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    var dateValid = false;
    //elementDay="#"+daySelector;
    $(daySelector).removeClass("input--error");
    $(monthSelector).removeClass("input--error");
    $(yearSelector).removeClass("input--error");
    console.log(daySelector);
    if (isNaN(day)) {
        console.log("day not numeric");
        $(daySelector).addClass("input--error");
    }
    if (isNaN(month)) {
        console.log("month not numeric");
        $(monthSelector).addClass("input--error");
    }
    if (isNaN(year)) {
        console.log("year not numeric");
        $(yearSelector).addClass("input--error");
    }
    dateEntered = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    console.log("in datemultiple" + dateEntered.valueOf());
    if(!isNaN(day) && !isNaN(month) && !isNaN(year)) {
        console.log("all fields entered")
    return this.optional(element) || /^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/.test(dateEntered.valueOf());
    }
    else 
    {
        console.log("some fields blank");
        return 1;
    }

    //  return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(dateEntered.valueOf());

}, "Please enter a valid date");

var validator = $("#form1").validate({
rules: {
        date_of_birth_day: { datemultiple1: ["#date_of_birth_day", "#date_of_birth_month", "#date_of_birth_year"]},
        date_of_birth_month: { datemultiple1: ["#date_of_birth_day", "#date_of_birth_month", "#date_of_birth_year"]},
        date_of_birth_year: { datemultiple1: ["#date_of_birth_day", "#date_of_birth_month", "#date_of_birth_year"]},
    },        

    groups: {
        date_of_birth: "date_of_birth_day date_of_birth_month date_of_birth_year",
    },

    debug: true,

    messages: {
                    date_of_birth_year: {
                        required: "Please enter the day, month and year",
                        min: "Year must be 1900 or more"

                    },
                    date_of_birth_month: {
                        required: "Please enter the day, month and year",
                        min: "Month must be 1 or more",
                        max: "Month must be 12 or less"
                    },
                    date_of_birth_day: {
                        required: "Please enter the day, month and year",
                        min: "Day must be 1 or more",
                        max: "Day must be 31 or less"
                    }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        switch (true) {

            case (element.attr("name")=="date_of_birth_day" || element.attr("name")=="date_of_birth_month" || element.attr("name")=="date_of_birth_year" ) :
                error.appendTo("#error_location_date_of_birth");
                break;

            default:
                // Append error within linked label
                $( element )
                error.appendTo("#error_location_"+ element.attr( "name" ));
                console.log("add to  ".concat(element.attr( "id" )));
                console.log("add to name ".concat(element.attr( "name" )));

        }
    },
        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        console.log("highlight ".concat(element.name));
        switch (true) {

            case (element.name=="date_of_birth_day" || element.name=="date_of_birth_month" || element.name=="date_of_birth_year" ) :
                //$("#form_group_date_of_birth").addClass("form-group--error");
                $(element).addClass("input--error");
                break;

            default:
                a2="#error_location_" + element.name + " span:first";
                $(a2).remove();
                $(element).parent().addClass("form-group--error");
                $(element).addClass("input--error");

                console.log("add class  ".concat(element.name));
        }
    },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {

        console.log("unhighlight " + element.name);
        switch (true) {
            case (element.name=="date_of_birth_day" || element.name=="date_of_birth_month" || element.name=="date_of_birth_year" ) :
                    //$("#form_group_date_of_birth").removeClass("form-group--error");
                    $(element).removeClass("input--error");
                    console.log("unhighlight dob day");
                break;

            default:
                $(element).parent().removeClass("form-group--error");
                $(element).removeClass("input--error");
                a2="#error_location_" + element.name + " span:first";
                $(a2).remove();

        }

    },
});

});
```

css

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.date-input__item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.input--error {
    border: 4px solid #b10e1e;
}
.form-group--error {
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-left: 5px solid #b10e1e;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The jQuery Validate plugin only evaluates the one field as a user interacts with it (or the entire form on submit).  It has no way to know that you want to evaluate validation rules on two other fields while one is being validated.

You must write a jQuery `keyup` and/or `focusout` handler function that programmatically triggers validation when and where you want it.  Use the `.valid()` method attached to the field where you want to trigger this validation.

**Example**:

```
$('.my_group_of_date_fields').on('keyup focusout', function() {
    $('.my_group_of_date_fields').each(function() {
        $(this).valid();
    })
});
```